# How to get the current language in Laravel while the url is not changing,

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

I am using two languages for my Laravel project. The default language is `English`. Another language is 'Bangla`. For that, I have created

- a folder inside `resources/lang/bn`.
- `Localization middleware` inside `Http/Middleware`.
- add `Localization class` inside the `kernel.php` under `middlewareGroups array`.
- add list item `english` and `bangla` in the menubar for choosing language `<li><a href="{{ 'locale/en' }}">English</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ 'locale/bn' }}">Bangla</a></li>`

So while I clicked any language my site URL is not changing but the menubar language is changed.

Now my question is **how can I find the selected current language in my blade template while my site URL remains same for selecting any language ?**

Comment: did you try app locale ?

Comment: not yet. how to do that?

Comment: Could you add your web/route.php

Comment: If you clicked a language, you can try saving it in the session. Then get the value of the session if you want to get what language is chosen

Comment: @aceraven777...yes I think about that. But I want to know that is there any other process in Laravel for that.

Comment: config('app.locale') should give you the current locale

Comment: @AhmedShefeer That is only what is defined in `config/app.php`, unless you have some trickery that overwrites it. Using `App::setLocale($locale);` is a way to do that.

Comment: @Qirel...It's `App::getLocale($locale);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use 
`{{ app()->getLocale() }}`